# Send multiple images form sdcard in android using Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory functon

Tags: android

below find the java file i dont no where it gone wrong but my app is unfortunately stopping ple can some one help me where and in which line i am going wrong..... 
below is my logcat ... details

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                      Process: com.example.ankita.implicitintent, PID: 16822
>                                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                          at com.example.ankita.implicitintent.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:82)
>                                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4651)
>                                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19310)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
>                                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   06-27 17:17:40.025 16822-16822/com.example.ankita.implicitintent I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 16822 SIG: 9

```
package com.example.ankita.implicitintent;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
{

    Button imgssend;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imgssend=(Button)findViewById(R.id.images_id);

        imgssend.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        Intent i=null,chooser=null;
        switch (view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.images_id:
                File Pictures= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                String[] listofPictures=Pictures.list();
               Uri uri=null;
                ArrayList<Uri> arraylist=new ArrayList<Uri>();
                for(String picture:listofPictures)
                {
                    uri=uri.parse("file://"+Pictures.toString()+"/"+picture);
                    arraylist.add(uri);
                }
                i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,arraylist);
                chooser=Intent.createChooser(i,"Send multiple");
                startActivity(chooser);
                break;
        }
    }
}


    here is xml file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.ankita.implicitintent.MainActivity">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/send_images"
        android:id="@+id/images_id"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks Like Something is wrong with the OnClick Override. Why dont you use the onClick Listener of the Button? 
Something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button imgssend=(Button)findViewById(R.id.images_id);

    imgssend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=null,chooser=null;
            File Pictures= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            String[] listofPictures=Pictures.list();
            Uri uri=null;
            ArrayList<Uri> arraylist=new ArrayList<Uri>();
            for(String picture:listofPictures)
            {
                uri=uri.parse("file://"+Pictures.toString()+"/"+picture);
                arraylist.add(uri);
            }
            i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,arraylist);
            chooser=Intent.createChooser(i,"Send multiple");
            startActivity(chooser);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: the above code also showing same problem that is unfortunately stopped